# symfony 2 doctrine relation OneToOne

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-one

How to get and set entity which `OneToOne` relation like my example.

I have error :

> Entity of type `Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\UsersInformatio`n is missing an assigned ID for field '`user_id`'. The identifier generation strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before `EntityManager#persist()` is called. If you want automatically generated identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping accordingly.

in php controller - I try save new item in this way:

```
$product = new Userstest();
$product->setUsername('aa')->setPassword('123456');
$product->setInformation((new UsersInformation())->setCompany('firma'));
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

when I save in this way

```
$code = 'test3';
    
    $product->setUsername($code)->setPassword('123456');
    $information = new UsersInformation();
    $information
        ->setEmail($code.'@a.pl')
        ->setUserId($product->getUserId())
    ;


    $product->setInformation($information);


    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($product);
    $em->flush();

 print_r($product);
```

and have

```
`* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO") UsersInformation.for` `user_id`
```

have :

```
Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Userstest Object
(
    [user_id:protected] => 9
    [information:protected] => Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\UsersInformation Object
        (
            [user_id:protected] => 5
            [user:protected] => 
            [email] => test3@a.pl
            [gender] => 
            [company] => 
        )

    [username:protected] => test3
    [password:protected] => 123456
)
```

It does not work
but when I remove `* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")`

I get this error:

> Entity of type Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\UsersInformation is
> missing an assigned ID for field 'user_id'. The identifier generation
> strategy for this entity requires the ID field to be populated before
> EntityManager#persist() is called. If you want automatically generated
> identifiers instead you need to adjust the metadata mapping
> accordingly.

```
Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Userstest Object
(
    [user_id:protected] => 9
    [information:protected] => Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\UsersInformation Object
        (
            [user_id:protected] => 5
            [user:protected] => 
            [email] => test3@a.pl
            [gender] => 
            [company] => 
        )

    [username:protected] => test3
    [password:protected] => 123456
)
```

Entities :

```
<?php
namespace Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity;
 
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="test_user")
 */
class Userstest
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 *
 */
protected $user_id;


/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="UsersInformation", mappedBy="Users", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $information;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $username;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
 */
protected $password;
```

---

```
<?php
namespace Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity;
 
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="test_userInfo")
 */
class UsersInformation
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $user_id;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Userstest", inversedBy="information")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="user_id")
 */
protected $user;


/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
public $email;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1)
 */
public $gender;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
public $company;
```

Answer (score 4):

Add `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` to the `$user_id` in your `UserInformation` class or use `setUserId` to set an explicit id for your entity.

**Explanation:**

The error tells you, that Doctrine needs an ID (the primary key of your entity) before it can persist the entity to the database. So you have to set an id or let doctrine generate an id for you. With the annoation `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")` you tell Doctrine to generate an appropriate id for this entity and don't have to worry about it.

**Edit:**

If you want to implement that `Userstest` and `Usersinformation` have the same id you can do it like that:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

$product = new Userstest();
$product->setUsername('aa')->setPassword('123456');

$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();

$information = new UsersInformation();
$information->setCompany('firma');
$information->setUserId($product->getUserId()); // Set the User Id

$product->setInformation($information);

$em->persist($information);
$em->persist($product);
$em->flush();
```

Comment: but i need to Userstest.user_id == UsersInformation.user_id so when i put new user new UsersInformation get id from user - how to do it ?

Comment: edited my answer... check if that fixes your problem.

Comment: i edit ask - both ways dont wor like i need - user_id for UsersInformation is not filled - i must first save Userstest then add UsersInformation to get id ? is not possible to this is auto value ?

Comment: You are right. You have to save Userstest first, so that it has an id. I updated my code example. To automatically assign the same id, check out the link in Rene Terstegen's answer. But to be honest, I would probably recommend merging these to entities into one (if possible).

Comment: i try witchout succcces : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663942/symfony2-doctrine-onetoone-complete-example

Answer (score 0):

If you have the freedom to modify the database to your needs I would go for the basic implementation of the one-to-one relationship (which means an extra column in one of your tables) and drop the requirement of sharing the ID's.

If you insist, maybe the link below gives is the solution (depends on the version of Doctrine2 you use):

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity

The documentation states:

> Identity through foreign entities is only supported with Doctrine 2.1

I'm not sure if this means it is only supported in version 2.1 or if it is supported since version 2.1

And remember that this kind of solutions have a performance hit compared to normal one-to-one relationships.

Comment: i try witchout succcces : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663942/symfony2-doctrine-onetoone-complete-example