# symfony2 doctrine onetoone complete example

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i try make onetoone relation from example - http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity

this is second try , first is here [symfony 2 doctrine relation onetoone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653209/symfony-2-doctrine-relation-onetoone)

Adres

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: grek
 * Date: 18.12.13
 * Time: 16:33
 */

namespace Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Adres {

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    public $street;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\User") */
    private $user;




}
```

User

```
    <?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: grek
 * Date: 18.12.13
 * Time: 16:33
 */

namespace Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity;


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User {


    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
     */
    public $name;



    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Adres")
     */
    private $adres;


}
```

and have :   php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force

[Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException]
  [Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping" in property Miejsce\ObiektyBundle\Entity\Adres::$user does not e
  xist, or could not be auto-loaded.
                                                                                               So where i can have error ?

- error was in syntax - i have @ORM/OneToOne but need @ORM\OneToOne now work fine ! :)

Comment: what was the point of this whole post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you are asking, but your annotations are not setup correctly.

```
/**
 * @Entity
```

should become

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
```

And

```
/**
 * @Id @Column...
```

should become

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column...
```

Same for `@OneToOne` should be `@ORM\OneToOne`

Basically you are not prefixing your annotations correctly.  You have `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;` but you aren't using it properly.  Prefix your annotations and that will get you going.

Comment: i get this syntax from doctrine documentation [link](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#use-case-2-simple-derived-identity)  - i cannot use doctrine documentation ?

Comment: you are not using pure doctrine.  You are using doctrine inside of Symfony.  The `@ORM` is there so you don't have to include multiple `use` statements.  It simplifies things.  If you want to follow the doctrine docs instead of Symfony docs, go ahead, but you can't expect to copy and paste and get it working.

Comment: ok now understand - this part but still dont understant why i canot setup onetoone relation like in example

Answer (score 3):

The answer is in the error message. Look at what is different between your two classes.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
```

Vs:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```

So update the one that is giving you the error.

**edit**

When you import Doctrine's annotations with `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`, you'll need to start all those annotations with `@ORM\`. The annotation-reader will know that `@ORM\Entity` will actually mean `@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Entity`, which is the class that defines that annotation.